# Unable to format date to a particular format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have imported data from a csv file to postgresql database and the date stored in the database column is in this format `'2012-27-3T19:00:18'` When I try to apply formatting on csv file it doesn't work so it is in `Varchar` datatype in the database. I tried to change the datatype of the column to timestamp and date and both time it returned this error

```
SQL Error [22008]: ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "2012-27-3T19:00:18"
  Hint: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
```

When I tried to apply formatting in Select statement it gave me same error. Is there any way I can change the format of the date to `'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS.SSS'` ?

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
select 
TO_CHAR(column12 :: DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MM:SS.00') column12 
from newtable n
```

When I apply same formatting technique on today date and time it works fine.

```
select TO_CHAR(NOW() :: DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MM:SS.00');
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the SQL statement you used to convert the column to the correct data type. You should also investigate the way you import the CSV so that you don't need to define the column as `varchar` to begin with

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please check now

Answer (score 0):

Well, your string value has a really strange format, as it has the day in the middle rather than the end, as one would expect from an ISO format.

You will need to use `to_timestamp()` with the proper format mask to convert that format:

```
select to_char(to_timestamp('2012-27-3T19:00:18', 'yyyy-dd-mm"T"hh24:mi:ss'), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MM:SS.00') 
from the_table;
```

---

But you should really fix your table definition and declare the column as `timestamp`

Comment: I am trying to change the datatype to timestamp but it is not working. Strange thing is when  I double click on the column in excel file it show `'` at the start of the date which once I remove it works perfect and after importing to database that `'`' is nowhere to be scene and still not working.

Comment: Your query works fine when I put the value in here but when I replace with the column name it gives this error which I believe is different 
`SQL Error [22008]: ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "2015-9-24T14:47:58"`

Comment: @MuhammadAsim: well apparently you have values that use `yyyy-mm-dd` and values that use `yyyy-dd-mm` there is no way you can reliably convert them. You will have to fix this at the source, i.e. you will have to fix the code that writes out those strange values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one!

```
SELECT to_char(date_column, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') FROM table_name
```

Try this format perhaps `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a strange format, having the day before the month but using a `T` as if it were a standard format.  This works:

```
select to_timestamp('2012-27-3T19:00:18', 'YYYY-D-M\Thh24:mm:ss')
```

If you don't want the timezone, you can remove it:

```
select to_timestamp('2012-27-3T19:00:18', 'YYYY-D-M\Thh24:mm:ss')::timestamp without time zone
```

Answer (score -1):

as the error is showing

```
Error [22008]: ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "2012-27-3T19:00:18"
```

> out of range

try to find the right column size (eg: at 20) that match to your date format.

Comment: and what could that be ?

Comment: i mean the column's size in your database.